# Confusion over poll() and recvfrom()

Tags: c, linux, sockets, polling, recvfrom

I'm trying to implement a protocol in C that sends/receives raw Ethernet frames, and I've ran into some problems using `poll()` and `recvfrom()` in a Linux environment. I think my problem is mostly conceptual, so I'll avoid posting my code for now.

I have two sockets for incoming data, and `poll()` is being used to indicate when data is ready on either socket through its return value and the state of the associated `pollfd` structure. This is working for me right now when I first run the program. For the sake of testing I'm only interested in ARP frames, and I'm able to use `poll()` to wait for an ARP frame to arrive. When it arrives, I call `recvfrom()` to copy the data into a location where I can process it. All of this is working fine.

The problem is that subsequent calls to `poll()` continue to report that data is ready to be read from the socket even when no new data has arrived in the socket. Once I've called `recvfrom()` and read the data from the socket, I'd like `poll()` to wait until a new frames arrive before reporting that data is ready. I've never used `poll()` before, so I'm not sure if there is an explicit step needed to "clear" the descriptor so that it will stop causing `poll()` to report data being ready until a new frame comes in. I'm clearing the `revents` member of the `pollfd` structures before calling `poll()`, but each call to `poll()` is setting the value of `revents` back to 1.

I've looked through the `poll()` man pages and I haven't had any luck finding information on this. I feel like I'm misunderstanding how sockets/polling works at a high level, so any help would be appreciated.

**[edit]** 
Here's the majority of my code. I've actually simplified the code for this example by including only a single socket. All of this is also encapsulated in classes and spread out, but re-writing it like this reproduces my problems. My final code has error-checking on the API calls and copies my receive buffer to process the frame rather than just printing the contents, but other than that it's pretty much the same.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <linux/if_ether.h>

int main()
{

    uint8_t sendBuffer_[1536];
    uint8_t receiveBuffer_[1536];
    struct pollfd pollStruct[1];

    printf("Making socket...");
    int mySocket = socket( AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ARP) );
    fcntl(mySocket, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
    char *options;
    options = "eth0";
    setsockopt(mySocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, options, 4);
    printf("Descriptor: %i\n", mySocket);

    while(1)
    {
        pollStruct[0].fd = mySocket;
        pollStruct[0].events = POLLIN;
        pollStruct[0].revents = 0;

        if( poll(pollStruct, 1, 0) == 1)
        {
            printf("New Frame Arrived: ");
            uint16_t frameLength = recvfrom( mySocket, receiveBuffer_, 1536, 0, NULL, NULL);

            printf("Destination MAC: ");
            for ( uint8_t i = 0; i < 6; ++i ) {
                printf("0x%x ", receiveBuffer_[i]);
            }

            printf("\nSource MAC: ");
            for ( uint8_t i = 0; i < 6; ++i ) {
                printf("0x%x ", receiveBuffer_[i + 6]);
            }

            printf("\nEtherType: ");
            for ( uint8_t i = 0; i < 2; ++i ) {
                printf("0x%x ", receiveBuffer_[i + 12]);
            }

            printf("\nPayload: ");
            for ( uint32_t i = 14; i < frameLength; ++i ) {
                printf("0x%x ", receiveBuffer_[i]);
            }
            printf("\n");

            //Clear buffer
            for ( uint32_t i = 0; i < frameLength; ++i )
                        receiveBuffer_[i] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I didn't mention this originally, but I'm trying to deploy this code on a Beaglebone Black. When I run this program in a VM with Ubuntu compiled using GCC, it works as I'd expect. After receiving/printing a frame, the program visually idles until a new one arrives. When I cross-compile the program and run it, the program continuously prints the same packet until a new one arrives. Since I'm clearing `receiverBuffer[]` whenever `recvfrom()` returns, `recvfrom()` doesn't seem to be clearing the data from its internal buffer once it's copied into my buffer, since it is continuously copying the data.

Comment: Please show your actual code. Is it possible that there is other data waiting to be read from the socket? AFAIK, there is no way to tell `poll()` to only look for ARP messages and ignore everything else. When `poll()` reports data is ready to read, what does `recvfrom()` actually return?

Comment: ... and are you using `MSG_PEEK` by any chance?

Comment: I added a stripped down version of my code with all of the same socket setup

Comment: Your code seems to be working for me on RHEL 6.

Comment: Thanks for the additional confirmation. I'm not sure if there's some generalization in my code that causes it to break with the ARM GCC compiler.

As a random side note, I changed `recfrom()` to `read()` since I'm not utilizing any network stuff in my call and the behaviour is the same on the Beaglebone

Comment: I think it's more likely to be a kernel or libc issue. Or perhaps there is some subtlety about the platform that you haven't accounted for. Have you tried using `libpcap`? Does it exhibit the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think the following might be a reason
* dont set revents in poll.It is actullay an output parameter
* Use some positive value in timeout. If you want infinite wait time use -1. Refer Man page of poll